# How to better define abbreviations by using variables?

Tags: abbreviations

I add the following lines in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:shell = "powershell"
cabbrev bter bo terminal g:shell
```

but that won't work (I got a `CreateProcess failed` error).
I have fixed with

```
exe "cabbrev bter bo terminal ". g:shell
exe "cabbrev vter vert botright terminal ". g:shell
```

Are there are any hidden drawbacks with my solutions?

Comment: Good question. By default I used to have `set shell="C:\\\\link\\\\to\\\\Anaconda\\\\powershell.exe` but then Vim became extremely slow. Therefore, I preferred Vim to "internally" use `cmd.exe` and open a `Powershell` terminal through a shortcut inside of Vim. This to avoid leaving Vim windows to do powershell operations in another window for Vim unrelated actions.

Comment: FWIW, there is no `"` in `:help :set` commands. `set shell="C:…` is invalid. It should be `set shell=C:…`.

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled it. The " should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass it a specific command to run, `:help :terminal` falls back to `:help 'shell'`. Therefore, you can do:

```
set shell=powershell
```

once and for all, which lets you keep your abbreviations simple:

```
cabbrev bter botright terminal
cabbrev vter vertical botright terminal
```

If you don't want to set Vim's default shell to `powershell`, then you can keep using `:help :execute`.

You might want to switch your concatenation operator to the generally preferred `..` but that is far from necessary in this case. Other than that, the approach seems fine to me.