# vert command works but v doesn't

Tags: command-line, split, abbreviations

To open a buffer in a vertical split, you can use the word "vert".
For example :

```
:vert term  #it opens a terminal in a vertical split
:vert sb1   #it opens the buffer 1 in a vertical split
```

Why i can't make the vert command shorter ?

On internet, i saw that people just write :

```
:vterm
:vsb1
```

For me it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

The full `:vert` is `:vertical` and the full `:term` is `:terminal`. In order to save typing, Vim lets you type as few characters as possible as long as there is no ambiguity so, for `:vertical`, you could type:

```
:vertical
:vertica
:vertic
:verti
:vert
```

but you can't go further because there are three commands that start with `ver`:

```
:vertical
:version
:verbose
```

and Vim can't really be expected to guess which one you want. Therefore, `:vert` is the shortest you can get.

The mechanism is described in chapter 20 of the user manual: `:help 20.2`.

Now… those people on the internet are probably using [or trying to use](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/39405/54) abbreviations, which are introduced in chapter 24 of the user manual: `:help 24.7` and thoroughly documented under `:help abbreviations`.

Comment: ":sb1" here vim understands 's' as split..But ":s/foo/bar" here vim understands 's' as substitute....It drives me crazy. Would you please explain that ?

Comment: `:sb` is short for `:sbuffer`.

Comment: OK you won again :| Thanks

Comment: @floupinette Part of the reason is that `:substitute` has been around since `ed`, so for backwards compatibility the shorthand `:s` needs to be `:substitute`. But as pointed out, `:sb` is the shorthand for `:sbuffer` (though I would guess that `:sb1b` would be interpreted the same as `:s/1/`; that is, delete the first `1` in the line or error)